# Can't connect to database java jsp, servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have to connect to database (MySQL workbench) with netbeans, I have file DBContext to dbcontext file to make the connection


DBcontext connect successfully

```
package database;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class DBContext {

    //USE BELOW METHOD FOR YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION FOR BOTH SINGLE AND MULTILPE SQL SERVER INSTANCE(s)
    //DO NOT EDIT THE BELOW METHOD, YOU MUST USE ONLY THIS ONE FOR YOUR DATABASE CONNECTION*/
    public Connection connection;

    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + serverName + "/" + dbName;
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }

    //Insert your other code right after this comment
    //Change/update information of your database connection, DO NOT change name of instance variables in this class
    private final String serverName = "localhost";
    private final String dbName = "db_ite1";
    private final String user = "root";
    private final String password = "buiduclong"; // password here

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test connection
        try {
            Connection test = new DBContext().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement testStatement = test.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM db_ite1.blog;");
            System.out.println("suces");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a function get data from database, it works and returns data

```
 public List<User> getAllUser() {
        String query = "select u.id , u.fullname, u.gender, u.email, u.mobile , u.roleid, u.statusid from user u";
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Connection conn = new DBContext().getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                list.add(new User(rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getBoolean(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getInt(5), rs.getInt(6), rs.getBoolean(7)
                ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        List<User> list = dao.getAllUser();
        for (User user : list) {
            System.out.println(user);
        }
    }
```

then I call this function in servlet but it returns no data, my List has size = 0
even though I check my getAllUser() function returns data
Code in servlet

```
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        List<User> list = dao.getAllUser();
        request.setAttribute("UserList", list);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("userlist.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Q. What exception was thrown? A. I don't know because I have an empty `catch` block. There are so many other things wrong with this it's almost comical. You have an unused class member `connection`. You aren't closing the `ResultSet`. You aren't closing the ``PreparedStatement`. You aren't closing the `Connection`. The `Class.forName()` line hasn't been needed since 2007. Fix your code and tell us what exception was thrown.

Comment: @user207421 i'm fixed it, i'm add this string to url "?useSSL=false" at DBContext and it's work

Answer (score -1):

i'm fixed it, i'm add this string to url "?useSSL=false" at DBContext and it's work